# How to run idempotence test for ansible role via Test-Kitchen?

Tags: ansible, test-kitchen

It is pretty easy with Travis-CI:

```
  # Run the role/playbook again, checking to make sure it's idempotent.
  - >
    ansible-playbook -i tests/inventory tests/test.yml --connection=local --sudo --extra-vars "take_ownership_of_tmp=$OWN_TMP"
    | grep -q 'changed=0.*failed=0'
    && (echo 'Idempotence test: pass' && exit 0)
    || (echo 'Idempotence test: fail' && exit 1)
```

but I cannot use Travis, because I need to test my role on Debian systems. I use Test-Kitchen with ansible_playbook provisioner.

For example:

my .kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: ansible_playbook
  hosts: test-kitchen
  ansible_verbosity: 2
  ansible_verbose: true
  require_ansible_repo: false
  require_chef_omnibus: false
  require_ansible_omnibus: true
  require_chef_for_busser: false
  ansible_omnibus_url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neillturner/omnibus-ansible/master/ansible_install.sh

platforms:
  - name: debian-6.0.10-64-nocm
    driver_config: 
      customize:
           memory: 1024
           cpus: 2
      box: puppetlabs/debian-6.0.10-64-nocm
      box_url: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puppetlabs/boxes/debian-6.0.10-64-nocm/versions/1.0.2/providers/virtualbox.box


suites:
  - name: default

verifier:
  ruby_bindir: '/usr/bin'
```

test playbook (test/integration/default/default.yml) is very simple

```
---
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - preconf
  vars:
    #some vars here
```

I may add second call of preconf role to the default.yml, but it is not helps.

With one call kitchen returns me a number of changed items:

```
   PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
   localhost                  : ok=12   changed=8    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

But with two calls it returns sum of items instead of two separate results

```
   PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
   localhost                  : ok=24   changed=10   unreachable=0    failed=0
```

So, how I can run the playbook second time and check the results for idempotence test?

Comment: Please add more information

Comment: @ValeriySolovyov added, but I think it is an abstract question, which is not tied to a particular configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved for myself with BATS test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats
#

#
# Idempotence test
#

@test "Second run should change nothing" {
    run bash -c "ansible-playbook -i /tmp/kitchen/hosts /tmp/kitchen/default.yml -c local | grep -q 'changed=0.*failed=0' && exit 0 || exit 1"
    [ "$status" -eq 0 ]
}
```

UPD Serverspec variant:

```
describe command('ansible-playbook -i /tmp/kitchen/hosts /tmp/kitchen/default.yml -c local') do
  its(:stderr) { should match /changed=0.*failed=0/ }

  its(:exit_status) { should eq 0 }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Both [`ansible_playbook`](https://github.com/neillturner/kitchen-ansible/pull/117) and [`ansible_push`](https://github.com/ahelal/kitchen-ansiblepush#idempotency-test) kitchen provisioners now support the `idempotency_test` parameter, which essentially runs the playbook a second time and checks for `failed` or `changed` tasks.

You could simply add `idempotency_test: true` to your `.kitchen.yml` like so:

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: ansible_playbook
  hosts: test-kitchen
  ansible_verbosity: 2
  ansible_verbose: true
  require_ansible_repo: false
  require_chef_omnibus: false
  require_ansible_omnibus: true
  require_chef_for_busser: false
  ansible_omnibus_url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neillturner/omnibus-ansible/master/ansible_install.sh
  idempotency_test: true

platforms:
  - name: debian-6.0.10-64-nocm
    driver_config: 
      customize:
           memory: 1024
           cpus: 2
      box: puppetlabs/debian-6.0.10-64-nocm
      box_url: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puppetlabs/boxes/debian-6.0.10-64-nocm/versions/1.0.2/providers/virtualbox.box


suites:
  - name: default

verifier:
  ruby_bindir: '/usr/bin'
```